# encodeURIComponent in elixir

Tags: uri, elixir, encodeuricomponent

looking for elixir way to encode a uri component ie
`javascript
encodeURI("&")
"&"
encodeURIComponent("&")
"%26"`

`Elixir
URI.encode("&")
"&"
pry(11)> URI.encode_query(%{k: " & "})

"+k=%26+"`

basically I want encode_query but not have to do key value map and also encode spaces as %20, not +

Answer (score 5, accepted):

found solution, uri.encode has default argument of

  `def char_unescaped?(char) when char in 0..0x10FFFF do
    char_reserved?(char) or char_unreserved?(char)
  end`

for the second argument, by passing  char_unreserved, the function will now encode reserved characters

`URI.encode(" & ", &URI.char_unreserved?(&1))
"%20%26%20"`

Answer (score 0):

`URI.encode/2` accepts second optional argument - a function to determine whether or not skip encode a char. So we can use the function that returns false (not skip) for any char:

```
URI.encode("&", fn(_) -> false end)
"%26"
```